# Bootstrap carousel com múltiplos itens e carousel default na mesma página

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tendo um problema em aplicar CSS em um carousel específico na página.

Quando tento aplicar **CSS** no `.carousel-inner .prev/.next` apenas no segundo **carousel** ele não funciona. Se eu retiro o `#secondCarousel` (na hora de aplicar o CSS) ele funciona, mas causa comportamento indesejado no primeiro carousel.

O exemplo do que estou falando pode ser visto nos links abaixo.

[Carousel default funcionando](http://www.bootply.com/tFDV026had) | [Carousel com múltiplos itens funcionando](http://www.bootply.com/xrIugr2z30)

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como resolver isso?

Comment: Os seus links com os exemplos não estão funcionando.

Comment: Os links realmente não estão funcionando. Se fosse possível postar um código de exemplo seria melhor.